# How should we handle "What if" questions?

Tags: discussion, scope, close-reasons

Questions asking "what if" are off-topic as per the [**Help-Center**](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask):

> **To prevent your question from being flagged [and possibly removed](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-questions), *avoid* asking subjective questions where …**
>
> - ...
> - you are asking an open-ended, hypothetical question: “What if ______ happened?”
> - ...

**How should we handle such questions?**

- I.e. is there a specific 'close-reason' we should be using?

Comment: *"How should we handle such question"* - Uh, I guess in the same way we already do all the time. And for that *"too broad"* and *"primarily opinion-based"* seem sufficient close-reasons to me, depending on the particular question.

Comment: I do agree with Napoleon personally.